# Is the use of the return keyword different in a function than a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My understanding was that the use of `RETURN` keyword causes an exit out of a stored procedure. I assumed it would be the same with a function until I encountered this code. In the function below it doesn't appear that `RETURN` is being used in the same way that it would typically be used in a stored procedure (otherwise SQL would've exited out of the function before the select statement was ever reached).  Would someone please clarify what the use of `RETURN` is in the following function?

```
 CREATE FUNCTION udfOrderInShipCountry (
    @shipCountry nvarchar(15)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT
        [OrderID],
        [CustomerID],
        [EmployeeID],
        [OrderDate],
        [Freight],
        [ShipName],
        [ShipAddress],
        [ShipPostalCode],
        [ShipCountry]
    FROM
        [Northwind].[dbo].[Orders]
    WHERE
        ShipCountry = @shipCountry



--Calling the table-valued function
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    udfOrderInShipCountry('Mexico');
```

Comment: In a function, return returns the data as explained by the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) - which should always be your first port of call.

Comment: Yes, `RETURN` is different. `RETURN` is a status indicator for a `PROCEDURE`, however, for a function it returns the type defined by the `FUNCTION`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you find confusing.  In a function, `return` returns the value of the function.

This is an example of a table-valued function -- actually a specific type called an *inline table valued function*.  The `return` is returning the result of the query, as a table to the calling query.

In either a stored procedure or function, `return` stops that execution and returns control to the caller.  However, the returned value is subtly different:

- A stored procedure can return an integer value as a status, but the status can only be used if assigned to a variable in an `exec` statement.
- A scalar function can return any single value and can be used anywhere a scalar expression can be used.
- A table-valued function returns a table and can only be used in the `from` clause of a query.